# Set margin relative to another object with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to have margin positioning for a div be relative to another object rather than relative to the edge of the view pane.

Here is the page I'm dealing with:
http://www.pikefin.com/phptest/site/main/index3.php

I put temporary borders around the divs to assist with the positioning. Looking at the text "We provide financial data analysis and alerting services.", I'd like to have spacing between the text and the twitter widget. I can force the positioning I want with `&nbsp;` and `<BR/>` but I was hoping there was a more elegant method with margins (or maybe some other way altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<div id="twittercontrol" style="float:left;margin: 10px 0 0 10px;line-height:1.8;">
```

To

```
<div id="twittercontrol" style="float:left;margin: 10px 20px 0 10px;line-height:1.8;">
```

Essentially, you're just adding right margin to the `#twittercontrol` element.

Answer (score 0):

you could assign a `width: 540px` and `float: left` to `#jq-intro` element (tried on the firebug)
but with this method you need also a clearing on the container (like easyclearing or other not-structural method)